# Filter only part of input using select

Tags: json, edit, jq, in-place

Given input like this:

```
{
  "type": "collection",
  "foo": "bar",
  "children": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": "GB"
      },
      "data": "..."
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": "PL"
      },
      "data": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I use `jq` to retain all of the JSON structure, but filter out some of the children using `select()`. For instance, If I wanted to return only children with country GB, I would expect the following output:

```
{
  "type": "collection",
  "foo": "bar",
  "children": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": "GB"
      },
      "data": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

If I only want the children, this is easy with `.children[] | select(.properties.country == "GB")`, but does not retain the rest of the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `|=`.  In the present case, you could use the following pattern:

```
.children |= map(select(...))
```

Comment: Thanks! I often struggle with getting my head around the jq documentation.